# Error when running jest tests - runtime.json cannot be read

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm wrote various unit tests and all of them seem pass except for one spec file which produces the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

Config file /Users/dfaizulaev/Documents/projectname/config/runtime.json cannot be read. Error code is: undefined. Error message is: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

import config from 'config';
        | ^
      2 | import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
      3 | import {
      4 |   ListObjectsRequest,
```

The error comes from this file `src/utils/s3.utils.ts:1:1` yet its unclear why.

**src/utils/s3.utils.ts**

```
import config from 'config';
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
import {
  ListObjectsRequest,
  ListObjectsOutput,
  ObjectList,
} from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
import logger from './logger.utils';

const S3_SYNC_TIMEOUT: number = config.get('S3_SYNC_TIMEOUT');
const AWS_REGION: string = config.get('AWS_REGION');

let s3: S3;

export function init(): void {
  s3 = new S3({
    region: AWS_REGION,
  });
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      /* Basic Options */
      "target": "es2019",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
      "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
      "lib": ["es2020"],                        /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
      // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
      // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
      // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
      "declaration": true,                      /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
      // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
      "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
      // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
      "outDir": "./dist",                          /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
      // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
      // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
      // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
      // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
      // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
      // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
      // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
      // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
      // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
  
      /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
      "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
      "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
      "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
      "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
      // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
      // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
      // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
      // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */
  
      /* Additional Checks */
      "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
      "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
      "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
      // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
  
      /* Module Resolution Options */
      "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
      // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
      // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
      // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
      // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
      // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
      "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
      // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
  
      /* Source Map Options */
      // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
      // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
      // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
      // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */
  
      /* Experimental Options */
      "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": false,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    }
  }
```

Please advise.

Comment: It tells you config is undefined. Are you importing config correctly? Do you need to destructure it with { config } ? Is your config library actually at 'config' or do you need to specify a directory like './config' ?

Comment: The logic `src/utils/s3.utils.ts` file works fine. That is how I import the config across the entire project.

Comment: What does `compilerOptions.paths` config looks like in the `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @slideshowp2 it's empty, I added the entire `tsconfig.json` to the question.

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev i have the same issue , if its resolved please provide an answer.

Comment: Hi @amarnathharish sorry, I could find the solution I implemented

Answer (score 0):

in yout test case, check if you have mocked any 'fs' module.

Comment: I did not, so not sure how I resolved it.